# laravel get user id in users table at the time of validation exists|users on call of api?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication, orm

I have started using laravel and I am loving it.
I write APIs for mobile developers.
I use lot of tables with joins on id_user.
thus I always need id_user.

I have table users which has columns as follows:
1.  id
2.  token
3.  full_name

I do validation as follows:

```
    $result=$request->validate([
        'token' => 'required|unique|exists:users'
        ]
    ]);
```

with above code I always get true or false in `$result`.
but I want the id of this token, which I use as unique in other tables.
thus

I fire the below query as follows:

```
    $users=DB::table('users')
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
              ->from('orders')
              ->whereRaw('orders.user_id = users.id');
    })
    ->get();
    $id_user=$users->id;
```

but my question is if in laravel validation, "`unique|exists:users`" checks for unique record existing in users table, and when it finds the record, it validates this constraint and (returns true), it must be storing this unique record somewhere.

Where can I get this record?
If laravel doesn't have this feature they must add it.

**Why should I join user table (or fire another query again?) and make the process expensive?**

Answer (score 0):

you need to create models and set relationships (User and Order)

```
  class User extends Authenticatable{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','token', 'password',
    ];

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}

class Order extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

set foreign key on orders table

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

then this should be the query

```
 'token' => 'required|unique:users|exists:users'

   $order = Order::find(1)->user()->where('token_in_orders_table', 'token_in_users_table')->first();
   return $order;
```

**Or create  a Resource for the Order Model**

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
//validate token
'token' => 'required|unique:users|exists:users'
//then
       return new OrderResource(Order::find(1));
   }
}
```

**Resource**

```
class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'order_details' => $this->order_details,
            'user' => $this->user()->where('token', $request->token)->first(),
        ];
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f7E4.png)

Comment: thank you for your answer.
but the question is, if validator checks for unique record existing in users table, and when it finds the record, it validates it, why should i join user table (or fire another query again?).

Comment: [Returns the Request Data from the Validator] (https://laravel-news.com/request-data-validator-improvements)